# Selective unfolding of values from Gremlin (Neptune)

Tags: java, gremlin, tinkerpop3, amazon-neptune

I have a vertex, say:

```
Vertex vertex = g.addV("person")
                .property("name", "x")
                .property(VertexProperty.Cardinality.list, "email", "x@yahoo.com")
                .property(VertexProperty.Cardinality.list, "email", "x@gmail.com")
                .next();
```

I am fetching values from the vertex using:

```
g.V(vertex).valueMap(true).by(unfold()).next();
```

I get:

```
{id=f862aa64-70d3-4c85-9bd0-1c938fdc2dc8, label=person, name=x, email=x@yahoo.com}
```

I wish to extract all the values of the property email, hence I do not want that apply unfold() to that property alone, how do I add this condition?

Also, I wish to do this in the one query itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `unfold` the `valueMap` by the number of values:

```
g.V().valueMap().by(choose(
      count(local).is(eq(1)),
      unfold()
      identity()
    ))
```

example: https://gremlify.com/bpy7apfj4yncr

Or you can use a simple `project`:

```
g.V().project('name', 'email').
    by(values('name')).
    by(values('email').fold())
```

example: https://gremlify.com/bqatjfi3rmrmt

Comment: So, the problem with the first solution is that if there is only a single email , it gets unfolded, and with the second solution I will have to explicitly name all the properties.

Comment: I know I cannot apply values() inside the by() since it is a valueMap, is there some way I can choose which properties to apply the fold on?